# Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server (centos 7)

Tags: apache, permissions, centos, httpd.conf, httpforbiddenhandler

I installed httpd on the host and changed the httpd.conf file as follows

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80


Include conf.modules.d/*.conf


User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/home/admin/domains/morabi.app/public_html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

when i loaded my ip address in browser it has "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server." error. and /home/admin/domains/morabi.app permission is 755 also files are loaded but my ip http://x.x.x.x/ has forbidden error

Comment: Did my answer work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the following to it:

```
<Directory "/home/admin/domains/morabi.app/public_html">
# Learn more about this at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

# Learn more about this at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride
AllowOverride All

# The solution for your error, allows your files to be served, learn more about this at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And restart Apache.

This is something that many people forget, and some don't know about. Please be aware of this.

### Edit

**Tip**: Take a backup before running these commands, I am not responsible if anything bad happens to the files.

Try checking the owner of the folder public_html by running `ls -la` inside morabi.app inside the terminal, if it is not your user or apache try running this command in the directory morabi.app:

Make sure you are running this as your primary user which you use, I suggest you not to change it to root.

```
chown $USER:$USER public_html -R
```

This above command is going to change the owner of the folder and the files inside it. Change `$USER` to `apache` if changing the owner to the user running the commands doesn't work, but always take a backup before as I said above.

Comment: Also try removing the lines starting with # sign.

Comment: I think I was wrong before but try this as I said above.